# Create circuit using circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I don't know how to create circuit like the image in the attachment.

[image: wanted]

Answer (score 9):

Here is a [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) solution. You may like the `circuitikz` input format but not like the shapes/sizes of the components; in that case, there are many options described in the [package manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/circuitikz) and in the code if you wish to explore and do some tweaking for your own circuit diagrams.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[
  europeanresistors,
  americaninductors,
]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0)
  node[above] {A}
  to[R=$R$,*-*] ++(2.5,0)
  node[above] {B}
  to[L=$L_r$,-*] ++(2.5,0)
  node[above] {D}
  to[C=$C$,-*] ++(2.5,0)
  node[above] {E}
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @datanhlg If this answer helped you, please mark your question as resolved by 'accepting' it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know [`circuitikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz), but here is a solution utilizing the Ti*k*Z library `circuits`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
        \path node [contact] (A) {}
            ++(right:2) node [contact] (B) {}
            ++(right:2) node [contact] (D) {}
            ++(right:2) node [contact] (E) {};
        \draw (A) to [resistor={info=$R$}] (B)
                  to [inductor={info=$L$}] (D)
                  to [capacitor={info=$C$}] (E);
        \path   (A) node[above] {A}
                (B) node[above] {B}
                (D) node[above] {D}
                (E) node[above] {E};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: @datanhlg If this answer helped you, please mark your question as resolved by 'accepting' it.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-circ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}
\newcommand*\Node[1]{\uput[90](#1){#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(9.2,1.35) % boundry found manually
\psset{arrows = *-*}
  % definition of node positions
  \pnodes(0.1,0.5){A}(3.1,0.5){B}(6.1,0.5){D}(9.1,0.5){E}
  % electrical components
  \resistor[labeloffset = 0](A)(B){$R$}
  \coil(B)(D){$L_{r}$}
  \capacitor(D)(E){$C$}
  % placement of nodes
  \Node{A}
  \Node{B}
  \Node{D}
  \Node{E}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}
\newcommand*\Node[1]{\uput[90](#1){#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(9.2,1.35) % boundry found manually
\psset{arrows = *-*}
  % definition of node positions
  \pnodes(0.1,0.5){A}(3.1,0.5){B}(6.1,0.5){D}(9.1,0.5){E}
  % electrical components
  \resistor[labeloffset = 0](A)(B){$R$}
  \coil[dipolestyle = curved, labeloffset = 0.55](B)(D){$L_{r}$}
  \capacitor(D)(E){$C$}
  % placement of nodes
  \Node{A}
  \Node{B}
  \Node{D}
  \Node{E}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]